# How to repair boot in a dual boot setup with two Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, grub, mbr, bootloader, multi-boot

I installed a second Windows 7 installation on a separate hard drive on a computer that already had a Windows 7 installation.

Initially all worked great - each time I restarted I received a boot menu where I could choose between two Windows 7 options.

First time I shut down the computer and turned it on again, it did not recognize any Windows 7 installation. Instead it gives me a GRUB error 22.

I tried booting from the Windows 7 installation disk, choosing language options and clicking the repair option at the bottom. It gives me a "System Recovery Options" window with two options:

- Use recovery tools that can help fix problems starting Windows. Select an operating system to repair.
- Restore your computer using a system image that you created earlier.

Of course I didn't prepare a system image beforehand. I would gladly choose the first option but surprisingly in the table just below the first option it doesn't show ANY Windows 7 installation.

What's funny is that under the first option it says "If your operating system isn't listed, click Load Drivers and then install drivers for your hard disks." So I click the "Load Drivers" button and guess what - I see all my hard drives and partitions! So actually it doesn't need additional drivers to see my hard disks.

Anyway, I clicked "Next" and received another window with various options.
 I followed the advice [here](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-installation-upgrade/42737-how-dual-boot-2-windows-7s.html), clicked on Command Prompt and executed `bootrec /rebuildbcd` it found both installations, but in the end it wrote "Element no found." (not sure if it's relevant for the second installation, or simply a statement at the end of that script).

I restarted and... GRUB error 22.

I tried to remove GRUB by

```
fdisk /mbr
```

and

```
fixboot
```

and

```
fixmbr
```

In all three commands I received:

> "'[command]' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Take a look at this one:  https://superuser.com/questions/896060/what-is-the-function-of-c-boot/1251608#1251608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions here:
http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Vista+Bootloader+from+the+DVD

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the motherboard battery is low or empty and upon shutdown you lose all BIOS settings, including Boot Priority, and you return to default options. Make sure the hard disk containing the "C:" drive is listed first in the hard disk Boot Priority in BIOS and then follows the other disk. This way your system will attempt to boot from that hard disk finding all the data it needs. You should see the boot selection as before and anything will be normal. If you mess with the boot order the system will try to boot from the wrong disk which is not bootable. It will then try the other disk which is bootable, but second in order, so the boot entries will never match and you won't be able to start either Windows 7 installation. Fix the Boot Priority in BIOS and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm not sure how true this is on modern systems which only use the battery for maintaining the RTC.